# Paypal Payment Gateway

Tags: php, laravel-5, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I want to integrate recurring payments using paypal for my application which is uk based and I want to use credit card as well for recurring payments.

I have checked [Paypal Payflow gateway](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payflow-gateway/) and it shows **Payflow Pro** is not available for uk.

Please help me Is paypal works for uk based application or not.
If not then what will be available gateways that i can use for recurring payments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the Laravel Cashier [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/billing) there are already Frameworks for your case (Braintree=Paypal)